# Destroying Session when browser closed - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I have sign_in page using remember me checkbox.
Remember Me - obviously to remember session forever (with 20 years expiration) unless you will click the log-out button.

The problem is, I can't sign in if I didn't check the remember me.

SessionController:

```
  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      if params[:remember_me]
        sign_in user
        redirect_to root_url
      else
        User.find_by_id(session[:remember_token])
        session[:remember_token] = user.id
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

SessionHelper

```
  def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
  end

  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end
```

Comment: You can make an ajax call to server to sign out when the browser closed.

Comment: check out http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password?view=asciicast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `create` method, you didn't actually mark the user as logged in when the user didn't check the remember me box. It only stores `user.id` in `session[:remember_token]`.

```
if user && user.authenticate(params[:password]) # valid email & password
  if params[:remember_me]                       # remember me
    sign_in user
    redirect_to root_url
  else                                          # do not remember me
    #User.find_by_id(session[:remember_token])  # this line did nothing
    session[:remember_token] = user.id          # store user.id in session
    redirect_to root_url
  end
else
  ...
end
```

Your `current_user` doesn't check `user.id` in session, but only checks cookies or manual assignment of `current_user`.

I would rewrite current user like this:

```
def current_user
  if @current_user
    @current_user
  elsif session[:remember_token]
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:remember_token])
  elsif cookies[:remember_token]
    remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

BTW. The title is irrelevant with the problem defined in the body.